# How to setup GitHub workflow CI / build to build each directory when something gets pushed?

Tags: github, build, github-actions

I've added GitHub Actions Workflow to my repo and tried to configure it but failed. Checked few websites but couldn't find a clear answer. How can one configure its Workflow so that C++ CI/Build would build each directory separately whenever I push something to the repository?

Note: My repo contains several folders of source code and each has different project/code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter each workflow to only run when commits affect files in a certain path:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'sub-project/**'
    - '!sub-project/docs/**'
```